# Get hardcoded char array from compiled C++ source

Tags: c++

It is well known that literal strings can be retrieved from C++ compilates. For example, the output of

```
g++ a.cpp
```

on

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    const char * secret0 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const char secret1[] = {
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
        0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
    };
    return 0;
}
```

can be inspected with [strings](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings). The output contains the strings:

```
strings a.out | grep -i xyz
```

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Is something like that possible for the hardcoded `char` array `{0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, ...}` as well?

Comment: Strings will output that if the charecters are within printable ascii range and size is greater than threshhold levels. If the chars are not in printable range then it is guess game. And heuristics For example a continuous 0x90 in text section might be nop whereas the same might be prefilled buffer in a read only section

Comment: If your query was as answered by mimak then you dont need anything more than grep -obUaP  escaped_hex

Answer (score 0):

Constants are usually saved in the `.data` segment (assuming ELF format), including arrays. You should be able to find it with any hex editor with a search function, for instance [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/)'s [Search Memory](https://fossies.org/linux/ghidra/Ghidra/Features/Base/src/main/help/help/topics/Search/Search_Memory.htm).